# Is it possible to share variable between SASS and Javascript in Vuex(Nuxt)?

Tags: sass, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

As in question. I use Vue, Vuex(Nuxt) and we also share all mixins and sass variables using:
[@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0"](https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module)

Which is newer version of ["nuxt-sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.5"](https://github.com/anteriovieira/nuxt-sass-resources-loader)

I know that there i spossibility with Webpack such as [here](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/how-to-share-variables-between-js-and-sass)
So my question is - is it posiibile to do it in similar way and how to configure it? What should I have installed and how can I add it to my nuxt.config.js?

EDIT:
I also found [that article](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript) but for me it is not working.

Comment: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage

Comment: @Aldarund I don't want to modularize my css. Sometimes we use external library and we need to add some styles as js parameters. That's why I want to share sass variable with js.

Comment: so the way to use css vars in js is to use css modules. And your article that u linked is for react. And its still use css modules in the end

Comment: I'm also interested by this question. The way I see is to hook on nuxt build and write json files with all sass variables. I'm currently trying to do that but missing a way to get all sass variables... I'm struggle with webpack :/

Comment: I am looking for better approach. I have all mixins, style shared across components and I just want to have access to variables not only inside style but also in components script section so I can even style thing inline with sass variables. So I believe it is more like Webpack configuration but I don't know for sure and how can I achieve this. @ManUtopiK please add +1 for better SEO

Comment: Thanks for editing and sharing article you found. It's working for me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

SASS offers the option to export variables, which you can import as module and use like any other object. Webpack with sass-loader and node-sass handles the imports.

Example:

```
// in assets/scss/variables.scss

$white-color: #fcf5ed;

// the :export directive is the magic sauce for webpack
:export {
  whitecolor: #{$white-color};
}
```

---

```
// in store.js

import Styles from '~/assets/scss/variables.scss'

export const state = () => ({
  styles: {...Styles}
})
```

---

```
// in component
...
computed: {
  styles() {
    return this.$store.state.styles;
  }
}
```

Longer answer: You can also just use css variables for everything.

E.g.

```
// in assets/scss/variables.scss

$white-color: #fcf5ed;

:root {
  --whitecolor: #{$white-color};
}
```

---

```
// in component
...
mounted() {
  this.$el.style.color = 'var(--whitecolor)';
}

<style>
.component {
  color: var(--whitecolor);
}
</style>
```

Comment: A little update to the CSS trick, 
in the `:root` body, 
`--whitecolor: $white-color;` should be changed to `--whitecolor: #{$white-color};` 

Source: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars